# Text.wordWrap set to Text.Wrap does not update Text.lineCount

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am using [Qt 5.13.1](https://doc.qt.io/), based on [Ubuntu Linux](https://ubuntu.com/) and I am trying to set the width of parent [Rectangle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) in runtime, based on its children's texts object size(s):

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window
{
    id: mainWindow

    property real ticketHeight: 0.00

    function printHeight()
    {
        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "Layout height:"+
                    " "+
                    mainLayout.height);

        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "ticketHeight:"+
                    " "+
                    mainWindow.ticketHeight);

        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "Layout implicit height:"+
                    " "+
                    mainLayout.implicitHeight);
    }   // printHeight

    visible: true

    width: 560
    height: ticketHeight

    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: mainLayout

        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle
        {
            id: mainRectangle

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            ColumnLayout
            {
                id: contentLayout

                anchors.fill: parent

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketTypeLayout

                    property bool heightAlreadyAdded: false

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketTypeTextValueEN

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Adult"

                        onTextChanged:
                        {
                            if(ticketTypeLayout.heightAlreadyAdded===false)
                            {
                                mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketTypeTextValueEN.height+
                                        ticketTypeLayout.spacing;
                                ticketTypeLayout.heightAlreadyAdded=true;
                            }   // if
                        }   // onTextChanged

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketTypeTextValueEN.height+
                                    ticketTypeLayout.spacing;

                            console.log("ticketTypeTextValueEN.height:"+
                                        " "+
                                        ticketTypeTextValueEN.height);
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketTypeTextValue (Text)

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketTypeTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTop

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "بالغ"
                    }   // ticketTypeTextValueAR (Text)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketZoneLayout

                    property bool heightAlreadyAdded: false

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketZoneTextValueEN

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Zone 1"

                        onTextChanged:
                        {
                            if(ticketZoneLayout.heightAlreadyAdded===false)
                            {
                                mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketZoneTextValueEN.height+
                                        ticketZoneLayout.spacing;
                                ticketZoneLayout.heightAlreadyAdded=true;
                            }   // if
                        }   // onTextChanged

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketZoneTextValueEN.height+
                                    ticketZoneLayout.spacing;

                            console.log("ticketZoneTextValueEN.height:"+
                                        " "+
                                        ticketZoneTextValueEN.height);
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketZoneTextValueEN (Text)

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketZoneTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTop

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "لمنطقة 1"
                    }   // ticketZoneTextValueAR (Text)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketRouteLayout

                    property bool heightAlreadyAdded: false

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketRouteTextValueEN

                        objectName: "ticketRouteTextValueEN"

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Mwsalat bus station 1"

                        onTextChanged:
                        {
                            if(ticketRouteLayout.heightAlreadyAdded===false)
                            {
                                mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketRouteTextValueEN.height+
                                        ticketRouteLayout.spacing;
                                ticketRouteLayout.heightAlreadyAdded=true;

                                console.log("ticketRouteTextValueEN.height:"+
                                            " "+
                                            ticketRouteTextValueEN.height+
                                            " "+
                                            "ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount:"+
                                            " "+
                                            ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount);
                            }   // if
                        }   // onTextChanged

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            ticketRouteTextValueEN.height
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketRouteTextValueEN.height+
                                    ticketRouteLayout.spacing;

                            console.log("ticketRouteTextValueEN.height:"+
                                        " "+
                                        ticketRouteTextValueEN.height+
                                        " "+
                                        "ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount:"+
                                        " "+
                                        ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount);
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketRouteTextValueEN (Text)

                    Text
                    {
                        id: ticketRouteTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTop

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "محطة حافلات موصلات 1"
                    }   // ticketRouteTextValueAR (Text)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)
            }   // contentLayout (ColumnLayout)
        }   // mainRectangle

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
        }   // Component.onCompleted

        onHeightChanged:
        {
            mainWindow.printHeight();
        }   // onHeightChanged
    }   // mainLayout (ColumnLayout)

    FontLoader
    {
        id: arabicFont

        source: "qrc:/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf"
    }   // arabicFont (FontLoader)
}   // mainWindow (Window)

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;height:237;width:560}
}
##^##*/
```

Now, everything works fine, however, last [Text (id: ticketRouteTextValueEN)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#details) object is [wrapped](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop) to 2 lines because of its lenght, which is ok. However, [lineCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#lineCount-prop) is not updated to value of **2 (two lines)**, but it returns **1 (1 line)**. Why and how should I count wrapped lines of [QML Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#details)?

**ADDENDUM A:**
I've change the objects holding info texts from [Text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#details) to [readonly TextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#details):

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window
{
    id: mainWindow

    property real ticketHeight: 0.00

    function printHeight()
    {
        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "Layout height:"+
                    " "+
                    mainLayout.height);

        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "ticketHeight:"+
                    " "+
                    mainWindow.ticketHeight);

        console.log("[QML]"+
                    " "+
                    "Layout implicit height:"+
                    " "+
                    mainLayout.implicitHeight);
    }   // printHeight

    visible: true

    width: 560
    height: ticketHeight

    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: mainLayout

        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle
        {
            id: mainRectangle

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            ColumnLayout
            {
                id: contentLayout

                anchors.fill: parent

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketTypeLayout

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketTypeTextValueEN

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Adult"

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketTypeTextValueEN.lineCount*
                                    ticketTypeTextValueEN.height+
                                    ticketTypeLayout.spacing;
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketTypeTextValue (TextEdit)

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketTypeTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "بالغ"
                    }   // ticketTypeTextValueAR (TextEdit)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketZoneLayout

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketZoneTextValueEN

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Zone 1"

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketZoneTextValueEN.lineCount*
                                    ticketZoneTextValueEN.height/*+
                                    ticketZoneLayout.spacing;*/
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketZoneTextValueEN (TextEdit)

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketZoneTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "لمنطقة 1"
                    }   // ticketZoneTextValueAR (TextEdit)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)

                RowLayout
                {
                    id: ticketRouteLayout

                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketRouteTextValueEN

                        objectName: "ticketRouteTextValueEN"

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "Mwsalat bus station 1"

                        Component.onCompleted:
                        {
                            mainWindow.ticketHeight+=ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount*
                                    ticketRouteTextValueEN.height+
                                    ticketRouteLayout.spacing;
                        }   // Component.onCompleted
                    }   // ticketRouteTextValueEN (TextEdit)

                    TextEdit
                    {
                        id: ticketRouteTextValueAR

                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: false
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter

                        readOnly: true

                        selectByKeyboard: false
                        selectByMouse: false

                        wrapMode: Text.Wrap

                        font.family: arabicFont.name
                        font.pointSize: 32

                        text: "محطة حافلات موصلات 1"
                    }   // ticketRouteTextValueAR (TextEdit)
                }   // ticketTypeLayout (RowLayout)
            }   // contentLayout (ColumnLayout)
        }   // mainRectangle

        onHeightChanged:
        {
            mainWindow.printHeight();
        }   // onHeightChanged
    }   // mainLayout (ColumnLayout)

    FontLoader
    {
        id: arabicFont

        source: "qrc:/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf"
    }   // arabicFont (FontLoader)
}   // mainWindow (Window)

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;height:237;width:560}
}
##^##*/
```

and now third [TextEdit (id: ticketRouteTextValueEN](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#details) is [wrapped](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#wrapMode-prop) to **2 lines** on screen:
[image: App running screenshot]
however, `ticketRouteTextValueEN.lineCount` returns **5** (5 lines), which is not ok. It should return **2** and because of that the contents of [Window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#details) is too scretched. Why is so?